# Transição de imagens com css3 - KeyFrames

Tags: css, css3

Eu estou tentando fazer uma animação com troca de imagens automáticas utilizando o `@keyframes` do `css3`. Estou copiando e colando o código do exemplo, mas sem sucesso. A transição entre as imagens estão ocorrendo de forma "doida". Vejam o snippet.

A animação que quero fazer é o DEMO 3 - com MULTIPAS IMAGENS:
[LINK - DEMO 3](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg1)

```css
#cf {
    position:relative;
    height:281px;
    width:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#cf img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
#cf img.top {
    animation-name: fadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
} 
#cf img.left {
    animation-name: fadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
} 
@keyframes fadeInOut {
    0% {opacity:1;}
    17% {opacity:1;}
    25% {opacity:0;}
    92% {opacity:0;}
}
#cf img:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://www.podagaita.com/img/fotos/imagem%20de%20aves%201.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="https://peregrinacultural.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/imagem-266.jpg" />
  <img class="left" src="http://s3.amazonaws.savoir.com.br/cea.com.br/imagem/cadastrocqlv/imagem/cadastrocqlv-53440.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O link que você forneceu não pode ser encontrado. E sobre o problema, o que de fato está acontecendo? O que que não está funcionando?

Comment: Corrigi o link @CelsomTrindade Quero fazer uma transição automática entre imagens com css3

Comment: Quantas imagens você está utilizando para fazer esse efeito?

Comment: Me equivoquei. É o SEGUNDO exemplo do DEMO 3. MULTIPLAS IMAGENS!!! Quero fazer a transição com 3 imagens.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Adicionei um Snippet ao código. Nele você pode observar como a transição de imagens está com o tempo "desregulado". Este é o problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorre pois você precisa alterar os valores de tempo e os % do keyframe para condizer com o número de imagens e tempo de animação e transição que você deseja usar, que é o que o tutorial recomenda. Veja como seria o processo:

> t=(a+b)*n

Onde:

a= Tempo que cada imagem ficará visível; Vamos usar 5s.
b= Tempo de animação; Vamos usar 1s.
n= Total de imagens; Vamos usar 3.

```
t=(5+1)*3; Logo: t= 18;
```

Agora precisamos calcular os valores de `%` dos keyframes.

> 1- 0% 
>   2- a/t*100% 
>   3- (a+b)/t*100% = 1/n*100% 
>   4- 100%-(b/t*100%) 
>   5- 100%

Ou seja:

2- (5/18)*100 = 27,77; 
3- ((5+1)/18)*100 = 33,33; 
4- 100-((1/18)*100) = 94,44;

Agora basta arredondar os valores e aplicar ao keyframe.

```
@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {opacity:1;}
    28% {opacity:1;}
    33% {opacity:0;}
    94% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

Por último precisamos apenas definir o tempo de `delay` para cada imagem, que seria: Tempo visível + tempo de transição * posição da imagem.

`(5+1)*1 (para 2ª img)` e `(5+1)*2 (para 1ª img)`

```
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
#cf4a img:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

Você precisa começar da 3ª pois você deve seguir a hierarquia DOM. Ou seja, a 3ª imagem está acima de todas, logo, ela deve animar primeiro para sair primeiro.

Veja um exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/q8wq4cm6/1/

#### Importante

Remova essa propriedade: `animation-direction: alternate;`

Ela faz com que a animação "vá e volte" ao invés de entrar em um ciclo. Ou seja, ela vai animar as imagens nessa ordem: 1 - 2 - 3 - 2 - 1. Ao invés de: 1- 2- 3- 1- 2- 3.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e pela ótima explicação @Celsom Trindade! Se não for pedir demais, poderia me ajudar com mais um coisa? As imagens precisam estar em cover (background-size:cover). Estou tentando introduzir direto nas tag <img> e também no arquivo css, mas sem sucesso. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Sim, isso é fácil, basta substituir as tags `img` por `div` com background. Só detalhe, elas devem ter a mesma classe, pois você controla eles pelo `nth-of-type(n)`. Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/q8wq4cm6/2/

Comment: Não sabia que o `cover` funciona apenas na `div` . Estava "me batendo todo" declarando na tag `img`e também na folha de estilos. Enfim, problema resolvido, mais uma vez obrigado Celsom!!

Comment: Ela até funciona na tag `img` mas como, por natureza, ela atribui os valores de width e height baseado na imagem (se não for especificado no css) não vai existir width nem height para a imagem, pode ser por isso que não deu certo para você. Na verdade, ela só não tinha dimensão. Mas nesse caso é melhor usar em uma div, pois se preencher o src da img, ele irá sobrepor o conteúdo.

Answer (score 1):

no caso, você precisa trabalhar com `animation` e não com `transition`... um outro ponto, é que precisa utilizar o `prefix` no `animation-delay`.

No seu `keyframes`, você tem que distribuir o tempo entre as imagens, como no exemplo abaixo estou trabalhando com 4 imagens, então dei 25% do tempo para cada imagem, se quiser trabalhar com 3 imagens, então será 33%.

Por fim, o seu `animation-timing-function` está como `ease-in-out`, se deseja uma divisão linear do tempo, use `linear`.

```css
#container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  
  opacity: 0;
  
  -webkit-animation: opacity 8s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: opacity 8s linear infinite;
  animation: opacity 8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  5%, 25%  { opacity:1; } 
  0%, 30%, 100% { opacity:0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes opacity {
  5%, 25%  { opacity:1; } 
  0%, 30%, 100% { opacity:0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  5%, 25%  { opacity:1; }
  0%, 30%, 100% { opacity:0; }
}

#container img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0;
  animation-delay: 0;
}

#container img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#container img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 4s
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

#container img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/105/105026.svg" />
  <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/105/105027.svg" />
  <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/105/105029.svg" />
  <img src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/105/105052.svg" />
</div>
```

Agora um exemplo onde a animação manipula o `background-image` direto sobre o content.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  
  -webkit-animation: imagens 8s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: imagens 8s linear infinite;
  animation: imagens 8s linear infinite;
}

#progresso {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 0%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  
  -webkit-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
  animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes imagens {
  0%, 20%, 100% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105026.png'); }
  25%, 45% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105027.png'); }
  50%, 70% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105029.png'); }
  75%, 95% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105052.png'); }
}

@-moz-keyframes imagens {
  0%, 20%, 100% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105026.png'); }
  25%, 45% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105027.png'); }
  50%, 70% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105029.png'); }
  75%, 95% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105052.png'); }
}

@keyframes imagens {
  0%, 20%, 100% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105026.png'); }
  25%, 45% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105027.png'); }
  50%, 70% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105029.png'); }
  75%, 95% { background-image: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/105052.png'); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  0% { width: 0%; }
  80% { width: 100%; }
  100% { width: 0%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes progress {
  0% { width: 0%; }
  80% { width: 100%; }
  100% { width: 0%; }
}

@keyframes progress {
  0% { width: 0%; }
  80% { width: 100%; }
  100% { width: 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="progresso"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mesmo do outro companheiro  ter respondido primeiro, a sua resposta veio de uma forma diferente mas também executa o próposito muito bem, obrigado também @TobyMosque. Se não for pedir demais, poderia me ajudar com mais um coisa? As imagens precisam estar em cover (background-size:cover). Estou tentando introduzir direto nas tag <img> e também no arquivo css, mas sem sucesso. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @Zkk, no caso do `background-size:cover`, como precisa setar a imagem como uma `background-image`, neste caso o ideal é não utilizar um elemento `<img>` e sim uma `div`, te aconselho a aplicar o `background-image` direto na `div#container` e utilizar o `@keyframes` para substituir o `background`.... adicionei um exemplo de como faze-lo.

Comment: @Zkk, aproveitei para adicionar um bonus, uma barra de progresso para a transição das imagens.

Comment: Entendo que funciona, mas é meio confuso a lógica: `0% { width: 0%; }
  80% { width: 100%; }
  100% { width: 0%; }` rsrsrsrs